# Restricting height of large image to height of smaller image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have two images centered side-by-side in a div. Both are restricted by a `max-width` property, but one image is significantly taller than another. I'd like the taller image to match the height of the smaller image *and* adjust its size based on viewport size.

My current code is as follows for the container

```
<div class="process">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/926x2260">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1584x1926">
</div>
```

with the CSS as

```
.process {
    text-align: center;
}
.process img {
    margin: 4rem 3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 40%;
}
```

A `max-height` of 740px looks perfect with a full-sized viewport but isn't responsive. I'd like this to be done in CSS and without an extra container for the larger image, but I'm not sure if that's possible. 
Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbjn8vLu/) to see what it looks like.

The images are a screenshot of a mobile and tablet layout of a website, so they should retain their ratio--if there's a better way to display these I'll take other ideas too!

Comment: Question is not clear: "I'd like the taller image to match the height of the smaller image" -- so the taller image can never get taller than the short image... "and adjust its size based on viewport size." -- how? Right now, when the viewport gets smaller, the small image goes below the tall one. Than what?

Comment: Yeah, should have made this easier. I want the heights to be equal, with the width adjusting depending on viewport size. They should retain their aspect ratios. I have media queries to stack them vertically instead for smaller viewport sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Make them size based on the parent div. Check this out:

```
.process {
    text-align: center;
    height: 70vh;
}

.process img {
    margin: 4rem 3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```